# Calculation in text file with sed and bc

Tags: batch-file, sed, calculator

I have text file

```
select 1
Something else 1
select 2 
Something else 2
select 3 
Something else 3
select 4 
Something else 4
```

I need all numbes near `select` word to change by some arithmetic law (say, increnented by 1)

Expected output (numbers advanced by 2)

```
select 3
Something else 1
select 4 
Something else 2
select 5 
Something else 3
select 6 
Something else 4
```

My attempts on Windiws (I used ported unix utility from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net , also all path in variable PATH)

bc - basic calculator

```
@echo off
sed -i -r -e "s/select\s[0-9]+/.../g" %1 | bc
pause
exit
```

Comment: "I failed" - What were the results you received, what were the results you expected. Did you receive any error messages (and if so, what messages)? Can you provide a sample data file?

Comment: I have no result, because I do not know something principal behaviour. I want my text file changed, the numbers near `select` words shold be changed

Comment: Should be incremented by 1 or 2, expected output is in the top of post, but with incremented numbers near `select`

Comment: @Tiw I had added Expected output

Comment: Do you insist on using `sed` and `bc`, or would another solution (for example, PowerShell or VBScript) be acceptable?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I prefer sed+bc but if you can demonstrate PowerShell, you are welcome, please.

Answer (score 3):

In pure batch without 3rd party tools (limited to 32bit signed integers):

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\29\SO_54425239.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal  EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Increment=2"
for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in (%1) do if "%%A"=="select" (
    Set /A "Number=%%B + Increment"
    Echo:%%A !Number!
) Else Echo:%%A %%B
```

Sample run:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\01\29\SO_54425239.cmd file.txt
select 3
Something else 1
select 4
Something else 2
select 5
Something else 3
select 6
Something else 4
```

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell can do it fairly easily:

```
$increment = 1                # How much to add
$sourcefile = ".\unincrement" # Full path of the original data
$destfile = ".\incremented"   # Full path of the changed data - should be different from original, but doesn't actually have to be with PowerShell.

(Get-Content $sourcefile) | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match "select (\d+)") { "select $($increment + $Matches[1])"} else { $_ } } | Out-File $destfile -Append
```

You can put the actual values in the last line instead of using `$increment`, `$sourcefile`, and `$destfile`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a GNU awk's job, not sed's:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";ORS="\r\n"} /^^select [0-9]+/{$2+=2}1'
```

I escaped `^` already. Try it, see if it works.
You can add `-i inplace` switch to change in place -- given your GNU awk is `v4.1.0`+.

That would give:

```
gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN{RS="\r?\n";ORS="\r\n"} /^^select [0-9]+/{$2+=2}1' %1
```

To replace the `sed` line in your batch.

To avoid problem, another way is use double quotes, like this:

```
> gawk "BEGIN{RS=\"\r?\n\";ORS=\"\r\n\"} /^^select [0-9]+/{$2+=2}1" input.txt
select 3
Something else 1
select 4
Something else 2
select 5
Something else 3
select 6
Something else 4
```

Btw, I used carriage return `\r\n` as `ORS` since you are on windows, you can change or remove the setting(default is `\n`) if you don't need carriage returns.

Comment: Where is the my inputted file? In Windows it is %1. $0=%1?

Comment: @Sergio  Oh, you mean the `$2`?  In awk `$0` means the whole line readed, and `$2` means second column.

Comment: I get   an error `^ backslash not last character on line`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/(select )(.*)/echo '\''x=2+\2;print "\1"; x'\''| bc/e;' file
```

Pattern match on `select` and its number, echo the bc commands through a pipe to bc and evaluate the commands using the `e` flag on seds substitution command.

An alternative, using bash:

```
sed -E 's/(select )(.*)/echo "\1$((2+\2))"/e' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) with a bit of user supplied JavaScript, assuming input file is "test.txt"

```
jrepl "(select )(\d+)" "$txt=$1+(parseInt($2)+2)" /jq /f test.txt
```

The output of the above will print to the screen (stdout)

Add `/o new.txt` to write the output to a new file, or `/o -` to overwrite the original file.

JREPL.BAT is pure script (hybrid JavaScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward without the need of any 3rd party exe file. Extensive documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged output.